# How hard would it be to provide Dart VM as a Chrome NaCl plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dart

Both Dart and NaCl are OS projects. I wonder how hard would it be to provide a NaCl plugin which could execute Dart code on any Chrome browser?!
The Pepper C/C++ API looks much better compared to wrapped JavaScript API.

Comment: What's the purpose for this? There is already Dart for Chrome work in progress?

Comment: I wondered this too. @Gunter would allow for shipping Dart in Chrome today (and also allow custom versions of Dart!)

Comment: I wouldn't expect a NaCl implementation to be ready in one day. Nacl has limited access to the DOM. This would need huge effort to be useable and still would not provide one of the biggest advantages of Dart - browser abstraction.

Comment: Unfortunately it is in progress since long time, without any promise to be finished soon. What makes me even less enthusiastic is the current state in Dartium where there are no native API in Dart for chrome packaged apps. Wrapping around the Javascript API is not the optimal way. The PPAPI has at least a C++ binding which might give a closer OO abstraction when wrapped in Dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nacl has several security restrictions that make it very hard (but not impossible) to execute Jitting VMs in it. It also doesn't have nice access to DOM, which would severely limit the usability of the VM. You probably want this approach only for C++ programs that use Dart as its scripting engine (for example in a game).

There seems to be a project that tries to port v8: [nacl-v8](https://github.com/p-march/nacl-v8/blob/master/README)

Their readme describes some of the problems:

- NaCl does not allow data in code segments.
- Executable memory must be provided from a special region marked by NaCl for dynamically-loaded code. I'm guessing that Nacl wants to do some checks on it, which would probably slow down execution.
- All code insertion/deletion/self-modification must be performed via NaCl service runtime calls.
- Code emitted by the VM must comply with NaCl security constraints (e.g. sandboxing of indirect jumps, instruction alignment).